# Get X/Y point of the actual form

Tags: vb.net, position, point

Simple question, but could somehow not find any answer on google (maybe it's just too late):

How can I get the coordinates of a form (current form => `Me`) of the upper left angle of it on the screen?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.NET the location of a form can be found using Me.Location.

You can set it using

```
Me.Location = new Point(100,200)
```

or get the location using

```
Dim Value as Point

Value = Me.Location;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim p as Point
p = Form1.Location

Debug.Print(p.X)
Debug.Print(p.Y)
```

If you want to set a form's location:

```
frm.Location = New Point(100, 300)
```

Comment: Hell ... so simple. Thanks very much!